# Laravel 4 - Sorting Data

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-4

I am building a website in Laravel 4. I have a table in my DB called Games which contains a list of games. By default, I am sorting these Games with:

```
$games = Game::orderBy('title', 'ASC')->paginate(20);
```

Users can select which Games they are currently playing. These records are stored in a table called Players which stores game_id and user_id.

A couple of relevant models I have created:

```
class Game extends Eloquent {

    public function players()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Player');
    }

}

class User extends Eloquent {

    public function players()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Player');
    }

}

class Player extends Eloquent {

    public function game()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Game');
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }

}
```

What I would like to do is, be able to sort my Games by most popular (most total players) so that the Games list can be viewed in this way. I have tried the following, but it was nothing more than a stab in the dark as I'm pretty new to PHP frameworks and Laravel.

```
$games = Game::orderBy(count($this->players), 'DESC')->paginate(20);
```

Obviously the count($this->players) is wrong, but I'm kinda stuck on this one.

Thanks. Hopefully that all makes sense!

:)

Answer (score 0):

You need to `JOIN` the tables manually then `SELECT COUNT(player.id)`, `GROUP BY (game.id)` and `ORDER BY COUNT(player.id)`.

Your final query should look like this:

```
SELECT game.*, COUNT(player.id) AS players
FROM game
LEFT JOIN player
    ON player.game_id = game.id
GROUP BY player.id
ORDER BY players
```

Generating this with Laravel query builder is pretty simple:

```
DB::table('game')
    ->leftJoin('player', 'player.game_id', '=', 'game.id')
    ->groupBy('player.id')
    ->orderBy(DB::raw('COUNT(player.id)'))
    ->select('game.*')
    ->get();
```

Note that we cannot alias the `COUNT` to `players` and we cannot use models (no way to `JOIN`).