# Laravel OrderBy comments in posts

Tags: sorting, laravel, comments, eloquent, posts

I have post and comments tables where of course comments belongs to posts.
I want to sort posts now with eloquent by amount of comments.
How can i do that in laravel?

I tried to order by date using:

```
Post::orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->paginate(6);
```

i want the same but sorting by comments with are on other database but they are connected in model.

EDIT:

I end up now having this query:

```
$post = Post::
        join('comments', 'comments.post_id' , '=', 'posts.id')
        ->groupBy('posts.id')
        ->orderBy(DB::raw('COUNT(posts.id)'))
        ->paginate(6);
```

{{ $post->author }} works...
but i cant get for example {{ $post->comment->count()}} from blade. In my previous query (above) it works. dunno why.

Comment: This could be a possible help for your first part of the question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19555259/laravel-4-sorting-data

Comment: Thank you for help. Its good to see that, but when i do this i cant use eloquent in blade for example like: $post->author (from users database) It seems that eloquent link is broken when i sorting it this way.

Comment: Can you post the query you're using ?

Comment: Sure, i edited first post. You can look at it please.

Comment: The following code will do the sorting in PHP as well as quite a few subquerires to get the counts, which is certainly going to be less efficient than doing it in MySQL, but it does give pretty nice (and readable) code: `$posts = Post::all()->sortByDesc(function ($item) { return $item->comments()->count(); });` In order to reduce the umber of subqueries, though it uses more memory, you can do the following: `$posts = Post::with('comments')->get()->sortByDesc(function ($item) { return $item->comments->count(); });`

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24208979/3251671) makes help.

> You should be able to use the `Collection`'s `sortBy()` and `count()` methods to do this fairly easily.

```
$hackathons = Hackathon::with('participants')->get()->sortBy(function($hackathon)
{
    return $hackathon->participants->count();
});
```