# Laravel OrderBy relationship count

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to get the most popular hackathons which requires ordering by the respective hackathon's `partipants->count()`. Sorry if that's a little difficult to understand.

I have a database with the following format:

```
hackathons
    id
    name
    ...

hackathon_user
    hackathon_id
    user_id

users
    id
    name
```

The `Hackathon` model is:

```
class Hackathon extends \Eloquent {
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'begins', 'ends', 'description'];

    protected $table = 'hackathons';

    public function owner()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('User', 'hackathon_owner');
    }

    public function participants()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('User');
    }

    public function type()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Type');
    }
}
```

And `HackathonParticipant` is defined as:

```
class HackathonParticipant extends \Eloquent {

    protected $fillable = ['hackathon_id', 'user_id'];

    protected $table = 'hackathon_user';

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User', 'user_id');
    }

    public function hackathon()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Hackathon', 'hackathon_id');
    }
}
```

I've tried `Hackathon::orderBy(HackathonParticipant::find($this->id)->count(), 'DESC')->take(5)->get());` but I feel like I made a big mistake (possibly the $this->id), because it doesn't work at all.

How would I go about trying to get the most popular hackathons which is based on the highest number of related hackathonParticipants?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Edit: If using Laravel 5.2 or greater, use kJamesy's answer.  It will likely perform a bit better because it's not going to need to load up all the participants and hackathons into memory, just the paginated hackathons and the count of participants for those hackathons.

You should be able to use the `Collection`'s `sortBy()` and `count()` methods to do this fairly easily.

```
$hackathons = Hackathon::with('participants')->get()->sortBy(function($hackathon)
{
    return $hackathon->participants->count();
});
```

Comment: How to change asending/desecnding?

Comment: `sortBy(Closure $callback, $options = SORT_REGULAR, bool $descending = false)`  Just set 3rd parameter to true.

Comment: sort by doesn't do that at the DB level...so it won't work correct with paging! Good for when you're returning a full set though..

Comment: got error laravel 5.5 : Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder

Comment: very bad performance though.
because it will get count of each row in a query. all of the counts should come within one query for fast results.

Comment: It would not get the count in a new query.  It's already getting all the results, then counting the size of the array.  If it was `$hackathon->participants()->count();` then you'd be correct.  It's calling the `count` method on the `Collection` object.

Comment: If you need to use Collection and not Query Builder this will do the job done. For descending order use sortByDesc() method.

Answer (score 272):

This works for me in Laravel 5.3, using your example:

```
Hackathon::withCount('participants')->orderBy('participants_count', 'desc')->paginate(10);
```

This way it is ordered on the query and the pagination works nicely.

Comment: Method `withCount()` was added in Laravel 5.2

Comment: just for info, if your relation name got Uppercase letter such as `maleParticipants`, the query should be like thi `withCount('maleParticipants')->orderBy('male_participants', 'desc')`

Comment: Thank you. In Laravel Backpack, I was able to use `$this->crud->query->withCount('contactTags')->orderBy('contact_tags_count', 'desc')`.

Comment: Great answer. Much better than the accepted answer because it maintains the query. The accepted answer works, but it is after the query is executed, which results in things like pagination not working and can become slow if the size of the collection returned gets large.

Comment: The order query can be more elegan with `->orderByDesc('participants_count')`.

Answer (score 50):

Another approach can be by using `withCount()` method.

```
Hackathon::withCount('participants')
        ->orderBy('participants_count', 'desc')
        ->paginate(50);
```

Ref: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations

Answer (score 15):

I had similar issue and using sortBy() is not suitable because of pagination, exactly as Sabrina Gelbart commented in previous solution.
So I used db raw, here's simplified query:

```
Tag::select( 
array(
    '*',
    DB::raw('(SELECT count(*) FROM link_tag WHERE tag_id = id) as count_links')) 
)->with('links')->orderBy('count_links','desc')->paginate(5);
```

Comment: Best solution I've found for earlier versions of Laravel! (new ones can use withCount) Not sure what it was but I had do to: `tag_id = tag.id` instead of `tag_id = id`...also, you can simplify this even more! Instead of doing `select` you can just do `orderByRaw('(SELECT count(*) FROM link_tag WHERE tag_id = tag.id) as count_links') DESC')->paginate(5)`. And for those wondering, you don't need the `->with` unless you're loading the relationship

Comment: And..you can also do this in a scope if you want to...`Tag::orderByLinkCount()->paginate(5)` then in your Tag model create `scopeOrderByLinkCount` with your orderByRaw statement

Comment: I beleive it should be `WHERE  tag_id = tag.id` NOT `WHERE tag_id = id`

Answer (score 6):

You can also use join operator. As Sabrina said, you can not use sortby at the db level.

```
$hackathons = Hackathon::leftJoin('hackathon_user','hackathon.id','=','hackathon_user.hackathon_id')
           ->selectRaw('hackathon.*, count(hackathon_user.hackathon_id) AS `count`')
           ->groupBy('hackathon.id')
           ->orderBy('count','DESC')
           ->paginate(5);
```

But this code takes all records from database. So you should paginate manually.

```
       $hackathons = Hackathon::leftJoin('hackathon_user','hackathon.id','=','hackathon_user.hackathon_id')
           ->selectRaw('hackathon.*, count(hackathon_user.hackathon_id) AS `count`')
           ->groupBy('hackathon.id')
           ->orderBy('count','DESC')
           ->skip(0)->take(5)->get();
```

Referred from : https://stackoverflow.com/a/26384024/2186887

Answer (score 6):

I needed to sum multiple counts and then use it to set order. Following query worked for me in Laravel 8.

```
$posts = Post::withCount('comments','likes')->orderBy(\DB::raw('comments_count + likes_count'),'DESC')->get();
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use below code

```
Hackathon::withCount('participants')->orderByDesc("participants_count")->paginate(15)
```

Or if you even want ASC/DESC with single method

```
Hackathon::withCount('participants')->orderBy("participants_count", 'asc')->paginate(15)
```