# How do I echo this?

Tags: php, laravel, object

When I echo this:

```
<?php echo $photo->votesCount ?>
```

I get

```
[{"photo_id":1,"votes":2}]
```

How do I display the votes (2)?

Here's a vardump of the object: http://pastebin.com/ddAkRk4c

If I type:

```
<?php print_r( $photo->votesCount )?>
```

I get this: http://pastebin.com/ZfE76WmB

The complete view:

```
2   @foreach($photos as $photo)                                                        
3   <li class='photo'>
4     <img src="{{URL::to('/')}}/uploads/{{$photo->name}}" width="150">                
5     <div>
6       <a href="{{route('photos.show',$photo->id)}}">{{ $photo->name }}</a>
7       <?php $photo_array = json_decode($photo);
8       echo $photo_array->votes; ?>
9     </div>
10   </li>
11   @endforeach
```

Part of the Controller logic:

```
 $photos = Photo::where('period_id', $currentPeriod)
                   ->with('votesCount')
                   ->get();
 return view('home', ['uploaded' => $uploaded, 'photos' => $photos, 'period' => $currentPeriod]);
```

Model:

```
  public function votes()
  {
      return $this->hasMany('App\Vote');
  }

  public function votesCount()
  {           
    return $this->votes()
      ->selectRaw('photo_id, count(*) as votes')
      ->groupBy('photo_id');
  }
```

Comment: use `print_r` instead of `echo`

Comment: add print_r() instead of var_dump();

Comment: it would be nice if someone with actual Laravel knowledge could answer - there has to be a Laravel way to access the values, all the answers so far seem like dirty workarounds

Comment: @Legionar Must have been a typo here? I'm writing <?php in my code... Else I don't think I'd get anything :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need for your second method `votesCount`. You have defined a `hasMany` relationship for the votes and if you query them you only get the votes for the photo-id.

To get the count of the votes do the following in your view:

```
$photo->votes->count();
```

And your controller should look like this:

```
$photos = Photo::where('period_id', $currentPeriod)
                   ->with('votes')
                   ->get();
```

Comment: Is there an easy way to sort the photos by vote count ? Maybe in the query?

Comment: Take a look at this answer on how to modify your collection like you described: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24208979/261713

Answer (score 0):

echo like this

```
<?php echo $photos->votesCount->votes ?>
```

Comment: Then I get Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$votesCount

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo $photos->votesCount->votes ?>
```

but you can also write

```
{{ echo $photos->votesCount->votes; }}
```

Comment: Then I get Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$votesCount

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Since it is a JSON array json_decode the array and echo the value

```
$photo_array = json_decode($photos->votesCount);
echo $photo_array['votes'];
```

Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Your `$photos->votesCount` returns a string, you have to convert it to an array like so:

```
$str = $photos->votesCount //gets the string
$arr = json_decode($str, true)[0]; //convert it to an array
echo $arr['votes'];
```

OR as an object

```
$str = $photos->votesCount //gets the string
$obj = json_decode($str)[0]; //convert it to an object
echo $obj->votes;
```

Comment: I get Undefined offset: 0 (for both answers)

Comment: just do away with the `[0]` part.

Comment: Then I get for the second : Trying to get property of non-object
And for the first one I get : Undefined index: votes

Answer (score 0):

i succesfully tested like this and had it echo 2:

```
$str = '[{"photo_id":1,"votes":2}]';
$arr = json_decode($str, true); //convert it to an array
echo $arr[0]["votes"];
```

so it shoud work for you like this

```
$str = '$photo->votesCount';
$arr = json_decode($str, true); //convert it to an array
echo $arr[0]["votes"];
```

if this doesnt work try to change the first line to

```
$str = (string)$photo->votesCount;
```

Comment: I get Undefined offset: 0

Comment: made a minor edit please try it out again and tell me if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a JSON array, json_decode the array and echo the value:

```
$photo_array = json_decode($photos->votesCount, true);
echo $photo_array[0]['votes'];
```

Don't forget to add second attribute `true` in `json_decode` - refer to [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

So the whole code:

```
<?php
  foreach ($photos as $photo) {
    echo "<li class='photo'>";
      echo "<img src='{{URL::to(\'/\')}}/uploads/{{$photo->name}}' width='150'>";
      echo "<div>";
        echo "<a href='{{route(\'photos.show\', $photo->id)}}'>{{ $photo->name }}</a>";
        $photo_array = json_decode($photo, true);
        echo $photo_array[0]['votes'];
      echo "</div>";
    echo "</li>";
  }
?>
```

Comment: I think, there is one more index with 0. What you get when you insert between that two lines this: `print_r($photo_array);`?

Comment: Array ( [0] => Array ( [photo_id] => 1 [votes] => 2 ) )

Comment: Undefined offset: 0. Also there's a foreach so I'm changing $photos to $photo in your code (and in every other that answered here :P)

Comment: If `print_r` returned that, then `$photo_array[0]['votes']` will work... you must have error elsewhere.

Comment: If I remove that part of the code then my view loads normally without showing the vote count. You can come on my teamviewer if you don't believe me :)

Comment: You had another error there: `@foreach($photos as photo)` has to be `@foreach($photos as $photo)` !!

Comment: I don't think I typed that anywhere? :( I just copied your whole code block and I got this: Undefined offset: 0

Comment: I still get Undefined offset: 0

Comment: Of course you get, because in your question you wrote wrong `$photo` and `$photos`, now I can see that...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93486/discussion-between-legionar-and-lextoc).

Answer (score -1):

The votesCount is an array. So just echo it like this

```
<?php echo $photos->votesCount['votes'] ?>
```