# How would I paginate these results in laravel?

Tags: laravel, pagination, pivot-table

I was reading this article to work out how to sort records in my database based on how many likes they have:

[Laravel OrderBy relationship count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24208502/laravel-orderby-relationship-count/36794833#36794833)

I came up with this which works:

```
$Book = Book::with('likes')->get()->sortByDesc(function($book_sort)
{
    return $book_sort->likes->count();
});
```

Which is based upon this Book model:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Book extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = true; 


    protected $fillable = [
    'title', 'author', 'category', 'featured', 'rating', 'description'
    ];

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Cat', 'id', 'category_id');
    }
    public function likes()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'favourite_books')->withTimestamps();
    }
    public function total_likes()
    {
        return $this->likes()->count();
    }
}
```

However now I am stuck on how I would paginate these results. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create manual pagination, try this:

```
$Book = Book::with('likes')->get()->sortByDesc(function($book_sort)
{
     return $book_sort->likes->count();
}); 

$paginator = new Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator($Book, 10);

return view('pages.homepage', compact('paginator'))
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think `paginate()->sortByDesc(function(){};)` will work properly here.

Comment: sortByDesc can be applied over collection https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections#method-sortby, the paginate method return a collection according to API of laravel https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_paginate

Comment: but maybe you can right @AlexeyMezenin, I haven't tested it before.

Comment: I get an error 'Method appends does not exist'. I have this at the end of my results page to print the page numbers: <div class="pagination"> {!! $Books->appends(Request::only('q'))->render() !!} </div>

Comment: @Magearlik What is Request::only('q') ?, I see you have $Books at the blade but in your question is $Book

Comment: Request::only('q') makes sure the search results get paginated. The search text field is called 'q' for query.

Comment: What about in your blade is `$Books` and the Controller `$Book`, this isn't your issue, right?

Comment: Even if I just do $Books->render() to show the page numbers it still doesn't work. I get Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::sortByDesc()

Comment: It is Books in the controller and the view.

Comment: How are you passing the data to the view?

Comment: return view('pages.homepage', compact('Books'));

Comment: try with `view('pages.homepage')->with($Books)`

Comment: Same error: 
"Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::sortByDesc()

Comment: I think the error is because sortByDesc creates a different data type then what paginate wants. And you can't do this by using orderBy as far as I know

Comment: you want to order by number of likes that every book, right?

Comment: Yep that works! However how would I get it to give me page numbers rather than previous and next?

Comment: @Magearlik, this can really be a perfomance hit. What are you doing here is getting ALL `books` with ALL `likes` and only then counting, sorting them out and paginating. It will kill your hosting's memory and CPU. Paginate is designed to query only part of data, that's why it's useful.

Comment: Ok so I should create a new table for counting the likes for each book?

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin is right, in case the records are so much the performance could be poor, so you can post your tables and structure to look at other alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

`sortBy()` and `sortByDesc()` are working with collections only. `orderBy()` is working only with column name. Also, getting results, sorting and paginating them is a perfomance hit. It will also can eat all the memory.

So, the only solution I can see here is to use `orderByRaw()` or even raw query.

Comment: This will give me this error "Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::sortByDesc()"

Comment: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::sortBy()

Comment: Ok, sorts are working only with collections. Please read updated post. Can you post your tables' structure?