# How do I get posts with most comments in Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have posts and comments tables in my database. Comments table has posts id as foreign key. Now if I want to sort posts with most comments, how can i do that in laravel?

Comment: please add code of what you're using to get users and comments

Comment: Pretty sure this is what you're trying to achieve https://stackoverflow.com/a/24208979/5844171

Comment: it's not duplicate of that question. those two questions are totally different @rbaskam

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This sorts the post by their comment count.

```
$posts = Post::withCount('comments')
    ->orderBy('comments_count', 'desc')
    ->get();
```

Comment: @yasaryousuf no problem. You can mark this as the answer then.