# Sort collection based on value of one to many relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm building a filter functionality (which already works). Now I just want to add an order functionality to it: Order by "artist name", "artwork title",...

The possible order values aren't "fields" in this table. I can't find a way to start this **"orderBy"** query. What I'm looking for is something like this:

```
$artworks = $artworks->orderBy(function($q) use($request){
    $q->where('title', 'LIKE', '%artist_name%');
});
```

But obviously this doesn't work. Is there a way to do this? 
**For example: I want to be able to sort on artworks that have a `title` "artist_name", ordered by the `value` of those records**

I have two tables: `Artworks` & `Artwork_data` (one to many relationship).

This is my `Artwork_data` table:

[image: Artwork_data table]

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz Can you be more specific?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel OrderBy relationship count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24208502/laravel-orderby-relationship-count)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `orderByRaw` with conditional clause

```
->orderByRaw('case when title like %artist_name% then value else somecolumn end asc')
```