# Ordering by foreign key field count

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I have three tables a product, user and purchases table. I am trying to return a list of the category of products that the user has most frequently purchased. So the list should look like : Garden 4, Food 3, Sport 2 etc.

Here are my tables:

**products**: `id, name, categories_id, price` 
 **categories**: id, category
**users**: `id, name`
**purchases**: `id, users_id, products_id`

I am struggling to work out how to do this, this is what i have so far

```
Purchase::with('products')->where('purchases.users_id', '=', Auth::users->id())
```

Comment: check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24208979/1858357

Answer (score 1, accepted):

explanation:

first we select all products purchased by the current user, than we join it with the products table, we group our rows with the **category** attribute, and in the we select category, COUNT(*).

implementation :

```
Purchase::where("purchases.user_id","=",Auth::user()->id)
          ->join("products","products.id","=","purchases.product_id")
          ->join("categories","products.categories_id","=","categories.id")
          ->select('categories.category', DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
          ->groupBy('products.category')
          ->get()
```

Comment: This is good but i have just realised that it is a categories_id field and the category list comes from a category table, how would this work and how would i return the category name and total through variables?

Answer (score 0):

Check if this is what you need :

```
$categories = Category::join('products', 'products.category', '=', 'categories.id')
->join('purchases','purchases.products_id', '=','products.id')
->select('categories.*')
->groupBy('purchases.product_id', 'categories.id')
->orderBy(\DB::raw('count(*) as product_purchase_count'), 'desc')
->get();
```